# Batch to segregate files according to name length

Tags: batch-file, command

I got files as follows in folder fol1:

```
wsd.11
fmsd.12
wsd.102
fmsd.203
typo
echo
```

I want to move files which have tow digits i.e. wsd.11, fmsd.12 to folder fol2,
also i want to copy typo and echo to fol2

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "my_folder=c:\fol1"
set "other_folder=c:\fol2"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:-d /b /s %my_folder% ^| findstr /e /r  "\.[0-9][0-9]"') do (
   move "%%~dpfnxF" "%other_folder%"
)

copy "%my_folder%\echo" "%other_folder%"
copy "%my_folder%\typo" "%other_folder%"
```

Will work only if the two digits are at the end of the file.

Comment: mv is not a Windows command and quoting needs to be used in all areas to cater for long filenames.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line (no batch)

```
for %F in (fol1\*) do @echo %F|findstr "\.[0-9]*$" && (>nul move /y "%F" "fol2" & (call )) || >nul copy /y "%F" "fol2"
```

The `(call )` clears any error so that the code does not fall into the copy section if move fails for some reason.

Double up the percents if used in a batch file.

Comment: Dave, your regexp will match 3 numerals on the end of the name too.

Comment: @foxidrive - I know, that is how I interpreted the OP's question. His list contains files with 3 digits, and he never explicitly stated he only wanted to move files with 2 digits.

Comment: `I want to move files which have tow digits`  <--- he misspelled `two`

Comment: @foxidrive - Doh. You are probably correct. So move if exactly 2 digits, copy if none, and leave behind if 1 or more than 2? Very odd specs. I'll leave my answer as is until I see clarification from the OP.